Why do floating legs have zero delta risk?
I am puzzled as to why floating coupon legs do not have a risk to the interest rate to which they are indexed. Consider a quarterly SOFR floating leg (imagine it is part of a float vs. float cross-currency swap, which only has a risk to the cross-currency basis, not either of the floating legs).
Consider for simplicity only two coupons: the first one $r_1$ in 30 days and the second one $r_2$ in 60 days. According to the New York Fed formula for SOFR compounding:
$$r_1=\left[\prod_{i=1}^{i=30}\left(1+\frac{SOFR_i*n_i}{360}\right)-1\right]*\frac{360}{d_c}$$
And analogously for $r_2$.
For simplicity, assume $n_i$ is always one and $d_c$ is always 30. Assume $SOFR_i$ is initially flat at 3%. Then we have:
$$r_1=\left[\prod_{i=1}^{i=30}\left(1+\frac{0.03}{360}\right)-1\right]/12\approx0.030036$$
And same for $r_2$.
The disount factors would be:
$$DF_1=\frac{1}{1+r_1}\approx0.97084, DF_2=\frac{1}{1+r_1}*\frac{1}{1+r_2}\approx0.94253$$
So the initial PV would be:
$$PV=DF_1*r_1+DF_2*r_2\approx0.05747$$
It is already obvious from the PV formula that an increase (decrease) in the $SOFR_i$ rates and a resultant increase (decrease) in $r_1$ and / or $r_2$ and the corresponding effect on the discount factors do not exactly offset each other.
As an example, assume a hike of 1% is projected just after the end of the first compounding period (i.e. the hike happens at $i=31$ and affects all $SOFR_i$ for $i\geq30$), then:
$$r_1\approx0.030036, r_2\approx040065, DF_1\approx0.97084, DF_2\approx0.933442$$
And the resultant $PV\approx0.067682$.
So from the formulas, as well as from the numbers, it should be clear that a floating leg is sensitive to an increase (or decrease) of the indexed rates. Then why does a float/float cross-currency swap only have sensitivity to the basis, and not the floating coupons on each side?

Because a leg of a cross-currency is not just a SOFR payment leg, it also contains an exchange of notional which is fixed (and has the opposite sensitivity to that you calculated here). Synthetically it is an FRN, and the value of a FRN remains the same as rates go up and down.

@Attack68: ok, thank you. Out of curiosity though, why does the short USD notional generate the same exact sensitivity as the floating coupons? Is it by convention? The floating coupons are quarterly SOFR which is compounded on a daily basis. What if you just pay overnight SOFR on the short USD? Then this is not compounded, but merely results in a stream of overnight coupons that you need to pay every day (if you keep rolling it over). Then you pay overnight SOFR and receive quarterly compounded SOFR: these are not the exactly the same.

I think, the confusion may come from the exchange of notionals, as Attack68 wrote. If you exchange of notionals on the 2 legs of the swap, then, although they cancel each other, and if the curve used to project floater coupons is the same as used to discount future cash flows, then the floating leg prices to (almost) par, and has (almost) no IR delta. This is true not only for USD & SOFR. Conversely, if you don't exchange notionals, then the net value and IR delta of the entire swap is the same as if you did, but the floater leg, like in your question, no longer prices to (almost) par.

The exchange of notionals only makes no difference if both legs of the swap are in the same currency. For a cross-currency swap, of course they make a difference, and are usually included. I thought this question would be a duplicate, but to my surprise, could  not find it answered in enough detail before. Here are a couple of old questions that may help you:  https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/49113 , https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/70346 , https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/80491

Short Story:
The OP forgot to include the final notional exchange: this component is crucial for the floating leg to be insensitive to rate changes.
Long story:
Let's do an example: a floating-rate note (i.e. FRN, or we can call it a floating rate bond: this is identical in cash-flows to a floating leg in a Xccy swap).
Let's assume two coupons and a final notional repayment (say notional of 100 for argument's sake).
Below, we can think of $r_1$ and $r_2$ as the compounded rates as per OPs question, but without loss of generality, these can be any rates that drive the coupon payments. The only assumption below is that the discount factors are using the same rates.
$$PV=\frac{100*r_1}{(1+r_1)}+\frac{100*r_2}{(1+r_1)(1+r_2)}+\frac{100}{(1+r_1)(1+r_2)}$$
We claim that the PV is always equal to par, i.e. by definition that would mean that the PV is not sensitive to changes in interest rates.
Proof:
$$100\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{100*r_1}{(1+r_1)}+\frac{100*r_2}{(1+r_1)(1+r_2)}+\frac{100}{(1+r_1)(1+r_2)}$$
Divide by notional:
$$1\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{r_1}{(1+r_1)}+\frac{r_2}{(1+r_1)(1+r_2)}+\frac{1}{(1+r_1)(1+r_2)}$$
Multiply by $(1+r_1)(1+r_2)$:
$$(1+r_1)(1+r_2)\stackrel{?}{=}r_1(1+r_2)+r_2+1$$
Multiply out the brackets:
$$1+r_2+r_1+r_1r_2\stackrel{?}{=}r_1+r_1r_2+r_2+1$$
Matching terms, we see they are equal. So the LHS is always equal to RHS: in other words, we showed that the PV is always equal to par, irrespective of the magnitude of $r_1$ and / or $r_2$, therefore by definition, the PV is insensitive to movements in interest rates.
If the OP included the final notional payment, he'd also get the same answer. So the final notional payment is crucial, otherwise indeed, if we consider just the floating coupons, these are sensitive to interest rate changes, even when discounted by the same curve.
In conclusion, the notional exchange at the beginning is not relevant to the sensitivity of the leg. But it is relevant to making the PV of the leg zero (otherwise the PV of the leg would equal the notional).

hi Jan "notional exchange at the beginning" your calculation holds nicely not only if the notionals are exchanged at maturity, but also for amortizing swaps, as long as the interest accrues on the remaining notional.

Nice!
https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/70426/54838 shows that Bloomberg has a setting for the DV01 calc that defined how it includes ot excludes notional exchange.
